# Wrong tag sequence in certain posts?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, question-order

I've been browsing MSE for quite some time and I'm familiar with the fact that,

All tags under a question follow the rule that, mandatory tags come first ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[support](/questions/tagged/support)[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)), followed by **red mod tags**. Regular (white) tags come last.

However [this question](/q/7322) has its red mod tag going to the last. I'm afraid this is a "general" bug that occurs on more questions.

Screenshot:

> [image: #]

Although the shot is taken from a mobile, this bug affects desktop view, too.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340503/4751173) is another, rather rare exception (on Meta Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago, tags didn't used to get auto-sorted by popularity, nor were the required and status tags sorted to the front - they just appeared in whatever order you entered them. The feature to auto-sort wasn't added until after the particular edit was made.

Comment: Hello mod. I see you modified the post mentioned in my question and it's fine now. How did that work?

Comment: Any edit to a question's tags will cause them to be reordered. So I just added a random tag and then removed it seconds later.

Comment: I think we have a dirty fix: Simply edit its tag and the problem exists on one less question. *You should totally drop that and try jQuery.*